# How can I add URL query params on react admin?

Tags: react-admin

http://localhost:3000/order/lineitem?status=created&filter=%7B%7D&range=%5B0%2C9%5D&sort=%5B%22id%22%2C%22ASC%22%5D

I would like to add a status parameter in url but I can't and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#filter-query-parameter

This mentions using history.push() from react-router to push new filters to the URL. I imagine you could use one of the hooks from react-router, like useParams() or useLocation() to get the current filter state, add your status to it, and then push it to history.

You may be able to also use the filter-related callbacks from the listcontext (if you're in a list): https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#filter-callbacks. Since your status parameter isn't actually a filter, I'm not sure if react-admin will complain when you try to set a "filter" that isn't really related to the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ReferenceInput there's a filter that can do that

```
            <ReferenceInput
            label="Product"
            source="q"
            reference="user"
            required
            fullWidth
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
            filter={{status: "created"}}
        >
            <AutocompleteInput
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                optionText="created"
            />
        </ReferenceInput>
```

and it will automatically passed to the backend as params